# CSS clash with parent website. Does reset solve the issue

Tags: html, css, web-testing

I'm building a widget. When testing, the CSS works well but when I add it onto other websites, CSS clashes with existing website CSS and if the width is 800px, I get a width of only 546px.

Say if the class of that container is container box Can I fix that problem using reset?

```css
.reset .containerbox  {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px 15px 5px 0px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 800px;
  font-size: small;
}
```

Comment: Use a webcomponent. These are designed to avoid exactly this kind of problem.

Comment: use !important after every declaration to tell the browser to execute those declarations only and cut out other which are clashing

Comment: @connexo is this  https://www.webcomponents.org/introduction what you're referring to?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Though I'd recommend MDN or Google as a ressource. https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to

1. attach a shadowDOM to your outermost element.
2. Move your component's `childNode`s into the shadow DOM, along with its styles.

```js
const cb = document.getElementById('containerbox');
cb.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' }).append(...cb.childNodes);
```

```css
h1 { color: blue!important }
p { background-color: blue!important }
```

```html
<div id="containerbox">
  <h1>Your component's HTML here</h1>
  <p>Not affected by outer page styles once it lives in your component's shadow DOM. (except CSS inheritance).</p>
  <style>
    :host { color: green; }
    h1 { color: red; }
    p { color: brown; }
  </style>
  Content without a specific tag surrounding it.
</div>
```

Comment: Fixed that using `[...cb.children]`. Though I'm not sure why this happens when iterating children directly.

Comment: Presumably. it's the same reason as what you'd get if you loop over the indices of the collection. Because the collection is live, as the elements move, the collection changes and the indices no longer point to the same elements as they did when the loop started.

Answer (score 0):

u forget semicolon

```css
.reset containerbox  {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px 15px 5px 0px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width:800px;
  font-size: small;

}
```